# WidgetKit: How to onBackgroundURLSessionEvents() to keep a Widget up to date?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

In [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date) they say

> "After invoking `onBackgroundURLSessionEvents()`, the system calls the
> urlSession(_:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingTo:) method of the
> URLSessionDelegate you supplied to the URLSession. When all events
> have been delivered, the system calls the delegate’s
> urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession:) method."

but I can't find any examples online where this is actually implemented.  In my case I need to download data from HealthKit in order to update my widget, how can I implement `onBackgroundURLSessionEvents()` to do this? Right now I'm using a `BGAppRefreshTask` in my main app to run and store the data to GroupDefaults the Widget can access but I'd like to be able to leverage the API do to this from the Widget itself.

```
  class RecoveryScoreWidgetViewModel {
        
        public func getRecoveryScore(prefersHRVSleepPrioritized: Bool, handler: @escaping (RecoveryScoreObject?) -> Void)  {
            
            RecoveryDataManger().downLoadHealthDataAndBuildRecoveryScoreObjectsFromPast(daysToLookBack:  -1, prefersHRVSleepPrioritized: prefersHRVSleepPrioritized) { (recoveryScoreObject, _, _, _) in
                guard let unwrappedRecoveryScoreObject = recoveryScoreObject  else {
                    handler(nil)
                    return
                }
                
                handler(unwrappedRecoveryScoreObject)
                return
            }
           
        }

    
}

struct RecoveryScoreWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "Recovery Widget"
    
     var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: RecoveryScoreWidgetProvider()) { entry in
           RecoveryScoreWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)    // << here !!
              .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1051151827, green: 0.1098071411, blue: 0.1184534803, alpha: 1)))
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Recovery")
        .description("")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall])
        .onBackgroundURLSessionEvents { identifier, completion in
            //How to implement????
        }
        
    }
}

struct RecoveryScoreWidgetProvider: TimelineProvider {
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> RecoveryScoreTimeLineEntry {
        return RecoveryScoreTimeLineEntry(date: Date(), recoveryScore: 75, timeOfRecoveryUpdate: Date(), isTemplate: true)
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (RecoveryScoreTimeLineEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = RecoveryScoreTimeLineEntry(date: Date(), recoveryScore: 75, timeOfRecoveryUpdate: Date(), isTemplate: true)
        completion(entry)
    }
    
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<RecoveryScoreTimeLineEntry>) -> ()) {
       RecoveryScoreWidgetViewModel().getHRVAndRestingHRDataAndCalculateRecoveryScore(prefersHRVSleepPrioritized: prefersHRVSleepPrioritized) { (recoveryScoreObject) in

           if let unwrappedRecoveryScoreObject = recoveryScoreObject {

                let currentDate = Date()

                let refreshDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 15, to: currentDate)!

                let recoveryScoreTimeLineEntry = RecoveryScoreTimeLineEntry(date: currentDate, recoveryScoreObject: unwrappedRecoveryScoreObject, isTemplate: false)


               let timeLine = Timeline(entries: [recoveryScoreTimeLineEntry], policy: .after(refreshDate))
                completion(timeLine)


}


struct RecoveryScoreWidgetEntryView: View {
    
    var entry: RecoveryScoreWidgetProvider.Entry
    
     var body: some View {
         RecoveryScoreWidgetView(RecoveryScore: entry.recoveryScore, timeOfLastRecoveryScoreUpdate: entry.timeOfRecoveryUpdate, isTemplate: entry.isTemplate)
        
    }
```